# Running as root without --no-sandbox In puppeteer

Tags: google-chrome, puppeteer, chromium, ubuntu-20.04

I have VPS with Ubuntu 20.0.4 version and I installed puppeteer on it
if not passed the --no-sandbox argument

the Ubuntu has Error

> :zygote_host_impl_linux.cc(90)] Running as root without --no-sandbox is not supported. See https://crbug.com/638180. TROUBLESHOOTING: https://github.com/puppeteer/puppeteer/blob/main/docs/troubleshooting.md
> Error

but if I have pass this arguments    `headless: true, args: ['--no-sandbox']` puppeteer is launched but
its has Error

> open new Page
> Error: Evaluation failed: TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'querySelectorAll')
> at pptr://**puppeteer_evaluation_script**:3:24

Is There any way to Launch puppeteer without  sandbox in Ubuntu? or if not please help me